# I want to convert a MySQL query into a Laravel ORM query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have the following tables.

```
items ,
orders,
suborders {order_id, item_id}
```

Following are my [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) relationships:

- `item` belongs to `suborder`
- `suborder` has one `item`
- `order` has many `suborders`
- `suborder` belongs one `order`

This is my raw SQL query:

```
select * from items where items.id in (
    select item_id from orders,
    sub_orders where (
    (orders.id =sub_orders.order_id)
    AND
    (orders.order_date >= "2019-11-05" AND orders.order_date <= "2019-11-05")
    )
)
```

Comment: Refer to this meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391114/5581565

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?